# cmd.exe is not taking any arguments

Tags: c#, cmd

Here is my code:

```
string command ="attrib +s +h " + dir + " /S /D";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo=new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = command;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

But this code is not working. The command prompt executes without taking any of the commands.

Answer (score 6):

`attrib` is a .exe itself already. You don't need to invoke it via `cmd`. If you want cmd to execute some OTHER program, then you need the `/c` argument anyways:

```
string command  = "/C attrib etc..."
                   ^^--- CMD argument
```

Or just have:

```
startInfo.FileName = "attrib.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "+s +h " + dir + " /S /D";
```